# How to map domain class with two instances of another domain class

Tags: grails, grails-orm, hibernate-mapping, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I have two domain class as shown below. The top level class Client contains three references to Address class. It is a kind of 1..3 relationship. I want the Address objects to be saved by cascading when I save Client. What is the correct way to map such a relationship?

```
class Client {

    Address primaryAddress
    Address billingAddress
    Address shippingAddress

    static hasOne = [primaryAddress: Address, billingAddress: Address, shippingAddress: Address]

}


class Address {

    String addressLine1
    String addressLine2
    String addressLine3

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`hasOne` maps the reference FROM the child to the parent ([docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/hasOne.html)).  So in your case, that would means each `Address` would store a reference to a `Client`, rather than an `Address` storing three references to `Clients`.  From the sound of your question, that is not what you want, so you can just remove the whole `hasOne` mapping and stick with simple references.

Comment: you are right. This is not what I want. But, I am unable to get to what I want.